# Why does this Python code work as it does? Please explain

Tags: python, function, procedures

In the CS101 course at Udacity, the trainer demonstrates procedures in Python by writing the following code to print out the bigger number of the two parameters *n1* & *n2*

```
def bigger(n1,n2):
    if n1 > n2:
      return n1
    return n2
```

So, for example, he does

```
print bigger(6,3)
```

And the code runs and prints out:

```
6
```

That's fine. My question is this:

Since he clearly states in the course that "return n2" at the end of the code will always execute whether or not the if statement is true or false, why is return not *always* n2? Why does it return n1 even when 'return n2' is outside of the if-statement? It should execute regardless of whether the IF-statement is true or not. So I'm confused. O.o

Comment: I like to think of it as #YORO: you only return once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not true that `return n2` will always execute.  If n1 is greater than n2, the first `return n1` will execute.  That returns from the function, and nothing else in the function is executed.  A function can only return once.

Answer (score 3):

`return` terminates execution of the function unilaterally. The code never has a chance to get to the second `return` if the first executes.

Answer (score 2):

If n1 > n2 evaluates to true, it will execute the first `return` statement - since it is inside the `if` block, and immediately exit the function, and there is even no chance to reach the second `return` statement at all.

On the other hand, if n1 > n2 evaluates to `false`, the first `return` statement is skipped, and now it reaches the second `return` statement and executes it.